# Else block in if-then-else statement missing in SPD2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

If i try to insert an If-Then-Else statement into an stage in a SPD-Workflow i am missing the else-block. But when i add the statement in the "Go-To"-block it brings up the "else". Am i missing the wood for the trees or is this desired?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To add `Else branch` > click on `if statement` then click on add `Else branch` from the above ribbon as shown below

[image]

Comment: Check other cases at [Why Else Branch is disabled In SharePoint Designer?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/else-branch-disabled-sharepoint-designer/)