# Can i end a workflow 2013 inside an IF statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, development, designer-workflow, workflow-manager

I have created the following list workflow inside SharePoint online using SharePoint designer:

[image]

Now as shown in the above screen, I am updating the current item inside the IF statements.

But inside some IF statements, I want to end the workflow so the other IF statements will not be executed.

Is this possible? as seems I can not define "**Go to End of Workflow**" inside the IF statements.

any advice or help?

Thanks

Comment: If the `IF` blocks are dependent on each other then you can use below `IF` condition in first condition's `else` block? will it work for you?

Comment: @GaneshSanap but the workflow only allowed me to define one IF statement and one Else ,, where i can not have for example "IF Else"..

Comment: You can put IF Action inside Else block of first IF Action. That is similar to If-Else-If.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Else branch > click on if statement then click on add Else branch from the above ribbon.

Then you can add if condition inside else block, then add Else branch, then add if condition inside else block...

[image]

Similar issue post for your reference:

[Else block in if-then-else statement missing in SPD2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195498/else-block-in-if-then-else-statement-missing-in-spd2013)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the workflow 2013 platform.
You can create stages and put the IFs in different stages.
To create a stage, click outside of the current stage and you will see the option on the ribbon.
At the end of each stage, you can set the transition to end the workflow.
You can also define IFs in the transition and set the workflow to go to the desired stage.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you explain you reply on more details?